# Python Postgres order by multiple columns then create new index

Tags: python, postgresql, indexing, psycopg2

I am using psycopg2 to connect to a postgres database.

the database has ~200 million rows and I am trying to create a primary key ordered in order of several columns ie

```
part_id, date, time
A001   2014-10-23  00:00:00
A001   2014-10-23  00:00:10
...
A002   2014-10-23  00:00:00
```

I can do the following:

```
ALTER TABLE data ADD COLUMN ID SERIAL PRIMARY KEY;
```

But how can I orderby part_id (which though is a varchar is part numeric as above) then date then time first and create the id column to the sorted table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a primary key on the tree columns:

```
alter table data add primary key(part_id, date, time);
```

However, many experienced SQL developers think that the primary key should only serve to identify rows and anything else. According to this approach, you should use a simple `id` primary key and create additional indexes if necessary, e.g.

```
alter table data 
    add id serial primary key,
    add unique (part_id, date, time);
```

This may seem suboptimal because it needs two indexes instead of a single one but in practice it is comfortable and avoids some unnecessary complications.

I strongly advise against attempting to create one integer column that would reflect the order according to other columns.